# Running "rails s" error (Errno::EISDIR) `read': Is a directory @ io_fread /public/dev_assets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.0.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:65:in `read': Is a directory @ io_fread - /Users/bellobabajide/workspace/rightbonus/public/dev_assets (Errno::EISDIR)
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:65:in `initialize'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:122:in `new'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:122:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/workspace/rightbonus/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/workspace/rightbonus/config.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/workspace/rightbonus/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/workspace/rightbonus/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /Users/bellobabajide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rightbonus/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing or commenting out this line of code in development.rb solves the problem:

```
config.assets.manifest = Rails.root.join("public/assets")
```